# redirectmacth problems with quotes

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

google indexed link:

http://domain.com/category/body-cosmetics/„gloria“-good-quality

I need to redirect to:

http://domain.com/category/body-cosmetics/gloria-good-quality

In htaccess I have code:

```
RedirectMatch 301 http://domain.com/category/body-cosmetics/(.*)gloria(.*)-good-quality http://www.domain.com/category/body-cosmetics/gloria-good-quality
```

But its not working...
any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try without the hostname and scheme:

```
 RedirectMatch 301 ^/category/body-cosmetics/(.*)gloria(.*)-good-quality$ http://www.domain.com/category/body-cosmetics/gloria-good-quality
```